# Truffle cannot pass array of addresses as constructor arguments during deployment

Tags: truffle, erc-777

I have a standard ERC777 Openzeppelin contract

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.9;
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC777/ERC777.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC777/IERC777.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC777/IERC777Sender.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC777/IERC777Recipient.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/introspection/ERC1820Implementer.sol";

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/Pausable.sol";

contract ERC777Token is Ownable, ERC777 {
    event BeforeTokenTransfer();

    constructor(
        string memory name,
        string memory symbol,
        address[] memory defaultOperators
    ) ERC777(name, symbol, defaultOperators) {}
}
```

when I tried to deploy it via Truffle in this migration file:

```
const Contract = artifacts.require('ERC777Token');

module.exports = (deployer, network, accounts) => {
  const [owner, user1Addr, user2Addr, user3Addr] = accounts;

  deployer.deploy(Contract, 'ERC777Token', 'ERC777', [
    user1Addr,    
    user2Addr,    
    user3Addr, 
  ]);
};
```

I got this error:

```
   Deploying 'ERC777Token'
   -----------------------
 *** Deployment Failed ***

"ERC777Token" hit a require or revert statement somewhere in its constructor. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all require conditions.
   * Adding reason strings to your require statements.


Exiting: Review successful transactions manually by checking the transaction hashes above on Etherscan.


Error:  *** Deployment Failed ***

"ERC777Token" hit a require or revert statement somewhere in its constructor. Try:
   * Verifying that your constructor params satisfy all require conditions.
   * Adding reason strings to your require statements.

    at /home/user2038/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/deployer/src/deployment.js:331:1
    at Migration._deploy (/home/user2038/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:68:1)
    at Migration._load (/home/user2038/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:54:1)
    at Migration.run (/home/user2038/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/Migration.js:202:1)
    at Object.runMigrations (/home/user2038/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:142:1)
    at Object.runFrom (/home/user2038/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/migrate/index.js:107:1)
    at module.exports (/home/user2038/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate/runMigrations.js:5:1)
    at Object.module.exports [as run] (/home/user2038/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/commands/migrate/run.js:41:1)
    at runCommand (/home/user2038/.nvm/versions/node/v16.15.1/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/core/lib/command-utils.js:190:1)
Truffle v5.5.26 (core: 5.5.26)
```

The contract can be deployed this contract to Rinkeby by Hardhat, but not via Truffle on my local network...
Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ERC777 can be deployed to a local Ethereum now.

previously I forgot to deploy ERC1820 first.

```
  if (network === 'development') {
    await singletons.ERC1820Registry(owner);
  }
```

See more information:
https://forum.openzeppelin.com/t/simple-erc777-token-example/746